# How can I get my measure values legend to appear?

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to get my measure values to appear as a color coded legend. But now they are only check boxes. Editing the filter does not show any options to do this.

[image: Worksheet]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you select Analysis -> Legends -> Measure Names you can add the legend back to your worksheet. You can also display that ledgend on your dashboard.